# Webpage will not render specified font

Tags: css, browser, fonts

I am having an issue with the webpage because the browser keeps rendering its own font, Open Sans,
    below is what the chrome inspector shows:

```
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
```

The browser keeps rendering its own font, Open Sans, below is what the chrome inspector shows. I am specifying in the external stylesheet to render Roboto:

```
  body {
      height:100%;
      margin: 0;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      background-color: #FFF;
  }
```

I am importing the font as the google font docs requires

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Inspecting the page its still:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
```

Same issue in different browsers. I have cleared the cache, tried different fonts such as 'Arial', tried different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow

You should try putting the `@import` of Roboto font in your CSS file
and removing the link version from your HTML _

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CSS file that has Roboto font is the last one rendered in your browser. Or just try this:

```
html, body { font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; !important;}
```